# A soft puzzle about a deaf ,dumb and a blind person

Tags: logical-deduction

A deaf person stole a blind person's hen and a dumb person witnessed it.How can the dumb person convey this to the blind person?

Comment: Dumb could also mean stupid and not mute in which case the dumb person can just speak to the blind person.

Comment: Hay buddeh, uhm... dat fella o'er thar went an' stole ya chikin!

Comment: I'm beginning to wonder if situation riddles make quality questions in any way, or if they should just be off-topic here... hm.

Comment: The question title can be read as implying one person. Does he play a mean pinball?